# How do I encode an object/hash containing strings into latin1 using JSON 1.x in Perl?

Tags: json, perl

I have a CMS and a server which uses the old perl JSON module (version 1.54).
I need to encode a hash/object with strings into latin-1 (the target page is 8859-1 encoded).

How can this be done?

My code so far:

```
use JSON;

my $json = JSON->new();
$json->to_json($str),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [JSON 2.x](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/JSON-2.57/lib/JSON.pm) module has the `$json->ascii` and `$json->latin1` methods, which tell the module to replace characters outside the ASCII and ISO-8859-1 character sets, respectively, with the equivalent `\uNNNN` escape sequences.

Unfortunately, the 1.x versions of the JSON module apparently (thanks, Quentin!) don't have these methods.  However, given that non-ASCII characters should not occur anywhere *outside* strings in valid JSON, it should be possible to escape them *after* the encoding step, like this:

```
use JSON;
my $output = to_json( $data );

# encode non-ASCII characters as \uNNNN escapes:
$output =~ s/([^\x20-\x7e])/sprintf "\\u%04x", ord $1/eg;
```

Note that the replacement above won't work for characters outside the Basic Multilingual Plane (i.e. with code points above U+FFFF).  To handle those, we need to use [surrogate pairs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Code_points_U.2B10000_to_U.2B10FFFF), which are probably best handled in a separate pass:

```
# encode non-BMP characters as surrogate pairs:
$output =~ s{([^\0-\x{FFFF}])}{
    my $c = ord($1) - 0x10000;
    pack "W2", ($c >> 10) + 0xD800, ($c & 1023) + 0xDC00;
}eg;

# encode non-ASCII characters as \uNNNN escapes:
$output =~ s/([^\x20-\x7e])/sprintf "\\u%04x", ord $1/eg;
```

Comment: +1 ok, accepted - seems like JSON1 uses an other internal encoding than JSON2. See this question too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16939248/perl-why-do-i-need-to-set-the-latin1-flag-explicitly-since-json-2-xx

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean to either encode a perl data structure into JSON, or decode a string (which is in the JSON format) to a perl data structure.

But just in terms of encoding a string to latin-1, have you tried [Encode](http://perldoc.perl.org/Encode.html#THE-PERL-ENCODING-API)?

Comment: it is not just a string, but an object containing strings - and those need to be encoded in latin1

Comment: Have you tried the `encode` and `decode` functions from the [Encode](http://perldoc.perl.org/Encode.html#THE-PERL-ENCODING-API) module?

Comment: Of course you can't, and that's not what I meant. When you encode the hash into JSON you're ultimately getting a string that represents your hash in JSON format. I think you can just encode that JSON _string_ to latin-1 for you to get what you're looking for.

Comment: hmm, nope, this does not work. after i json encoded my string/hash i get '\xc3\xa4' and thats the same after i use encode("iso-8859-1", $str );