# Perl: Why do i need to set the latin1 flag explicitly since JSON 2.xx?

Tags: json, perl

Since JSON 2.xx i need to set the `latin1` flag in order to get umlauts safe to the html document:

```
my $obj_with_umlauts = {
    title  => 'geändert',
}


my $json = JSON->new()->latin1(1)->encode($obj_with_umlauts);
```

This was not necessary using JSON 1.xx :

```
my $json = JSON->new()->objToJson($obj_with_umlauts);
```

The html document is in iso-8559-1 (meta-tag).

**Can anybody explain to me why?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What are you talking about?

```
$ perl -MJSON -E'
   say $JSON::VERSION;
   my $json = JSON->new()->objToJson(["\xE4"]);
   say sprintf "%v02X", $json;
'
1.15
5B.22.E4.22.5D         # Unicode code points for ["ä"]

$ perl -MJSON -E'
   say $JSON::VERSION;
   my $json = JSON->new()->encode(["\xE4"]);
   say sprintf "%v02X", $json;
'
2.59
5B.22.E4.22.5D         # Unicode code points for ["ä"]
```

Those two strings are identical! In fact, adding `->latin1()` doesn't change anything because the iso-8859-1 encoding of Unicode code point U+00E4 is E4.

```
$ perl -MJSON -E'
   say $JSON::VERSION;
   my $json = JSON->new()->latin1()->encode(["\xE4"]);
   say sprintf "%v02X", $json;
'
2.59
5B.22.E4.22.5D         # iso-8859-1 encoding of ["ä"]
```

There is one difference between the last two: it's stored differently in the scalar. That should make absolutely no difference. If code treats them differently, then that code is incorrectly reading the data in the scalar, and *that* code is buggy.

---

> $string_with_umlauts definetly is a string in winLatin

Well, that's error number one.

JSON expects strings of decoded text (strings of Unicode code points), not encoded text.

That said, there happens to be no difference between a string encoded using iso-8859-1 and a string of Unicode code points. For example, when encoded using iso-8859-1, "ä" is byte E4, and it's Unicode code point U+00E4, two different notation for the same number.

If the string is encoded using cp1252, though, you'll have problems with characters €‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š‹ŒŽ‘’“”•–—˜™š›œžŸ (the characters in cp1252 but not in iso-8859-1). For example, when encoded using cp1252, "€" is byte 80, but it's Unicode code point U+20AC. 0x80 != 0x20AC.

> The html document is in iso-8559-1 (meta-tag).

Then at some point, you'll have to encode the output into iso-8859-1. You can do it using an `:encoding` layer, or using Encode's `encode` or using JSON's `->latin1` directive. The advantage of using this final option is that it will cause JSON to escape any character outside of the iso-8859-1 character set before attempting to encode it.

> Can anybody explain to me why?

You have a code (an XS module) that reads the underlying string buffer of the scalar and incorrectly treats that as the content of the string. There is a bug is in that module.

Answer (score 6):

This is such a huge can of worms that you're opening here.

I suspect that the answer is something along the lines of "a bug was fixed in the character handling of JSON.pm". But it's hard to know what is going on without a lot more information about your situation.

How is `$string_with_umlauts` being set? How are you encoding the data that you write to the HTML document?

Do you want to handle utf8 data correctly (you really should) or are you happy assuming that you live in a Latin1 world?

It's important to realise that if you completely ignore Unicode considerations then it can often seem that your programs are working correctly as errors often cancel each other out. When you start to address Unicode issues, it can seem that your programs are getting worse until you address all of the issues.

The [Perl Unicode Tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunitut.html) is a good place to start learning about these things.

P.S. It's "Perl", not "PERL".

Comment: By "winLatin", I assume you mean CP-1252. In which case you need to be even more careful as that encoding is not exactly the same as Latin1. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252 for the differences.

Comment: Also, this is a good example of where things used to work because of errors cancelling each other out. `$string_with_umlauts` should not be in CP-1252 at this point. You should decode it into a Perl character string as soon as it enters your program.

Comment: even Encode::encode_utf8($obj_with_umlauts) before i json encode the whole thing doesn't help - the characters are scrambled on the document without the latin1 flag

Comment: No. It probably won't. You need to read the Unicode tutorial and follow its instructions. Specifically, decode the data as it's read into your program and encode it as it's output.

Comment: that's what i did. i utf8-encoded $obj_with_umlauts and then encoded it using the json-module (without latin1-flag), can you show me some example code?